# unix, vi editor, copy and paste, not pasting first lines

Tags: unix, vim

I am performing the below steps.
Looks like I am not able to copy and paste into vi editor on unix with #!/bin/ksh as the first line. I pasted the code I need in but I do not see that in first line in vi editor. I have tried right clicking to copy and paste and also shirt+insert.

1. Open a session in Putty and login using credentials
2. Type and enter “vi .profile” (this opens a text editor within Putty)
3. Copy and paste (shirt+insert) the following text into the profile (“#!/bin/ksh” must be the first line)

   ```
   #!/bin/ksh
   set -o vi
   ## Command line aliases ##
   alias x="xterm -ls -sb&"
   alias p="ps -fu $LOGNAME"
   alias j="jobs"
   alias sasdir="cd /gfs_sastmp/sastmp049"
   alias w="find /gfs_sastmp/sastmp049 -type f -user $LOGNAME 2>/dev/null -exec ls -lrt {} \;"
   alias myprof="vi ~/.profile"
   alias resync=". $HOME/.profile"
   alias myenv="vi ~/sas_unix.sas"
   alias s="find ./ -type f 2>/dev/null -exec ls -lrt {} \;|grep -i"
   alias u="du -lag"
   alias mdr1="/gfs_bin/sas/update_pwd/setpass_rc.ksh $LOGNAME@LDAP DWPRD"
   alias mdr2="/gfs_bin/sas/update_pwd/setpass_sm.ksh $LOGNAME@LDAP DWPRD"
   alias unarch="/gfs_bin/sas/compression/uncompress.bsh"
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set vi to insert mode; otherwise the first letter that does so will mark the start of the insert. Either put vi in insert mode before doing the paste, or start the copied text with `i`, `o`, or some other insert mode command.